# How to know which Docker image is used for .NET SDK latest tag?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerhub

There's a current version of .net sdk 5.0 on docker hub:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk

If I run `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` with tag 5.0, what will exactly be downloaded and used?

There are many versions in **Full Tag Listing** section with tag *5.0* or *latest*

I'm not even sure if it's on top of Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This .NET SDK image page doesn't include the standard Docker Hub tag listing, but often in amidst the very long listing of names like `6.0.100-preview.7-focal-amd64` or `3.1.412-bionic-arm64v8` there will in fact be just a `5.0`.

In this specific case, the image includes versions for each supported architecture, and so you will get whichever one matches your local Docker.  The list of tags has a section for each supported architecture and where there is a `5.0` it seems to be in the first line.

[image: Screen shot of the Docker Hub page, with "5.0" highlighted]

As of this writing, on Linux the default `5.0` images are generally based on Debian "Buster"; on Windows, Nano Server 2022.